# How to extract the desired strings from a bracketed string

Tags: java

Sorry for the bad title. Feel free to make a better title.

I have a string like follows

```
[Munich, Germany],[Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada],...
```

Now i want to convert this list into a LinkedList locations
where

```
 so 0 index -> Munich, Germany
      1 index -> Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada
```

and so on..

How can i do this very efficiently in java. I thought of using string.split() but will that would be the efficient way to do something like this.

Comment: Split could be the only solution..

Comment: show your code what u have tried

Comment: You're sure that's not JSON??

Comment: @HotLicks: Doesn't look like JSON

Comment: @GIJoe - Depends on what the OP has omitted and what tool was used to produce the listing.

Comment: @HotLicks: That would mean he omitted curly braces, colons, and quotes, along with any field names meant to recreate the javascript object :)

Comment: @GIJoe - All he'd really have to omit is quotes.

Comment: @HotLicks: JSONLint won't validate it if you put each string into quotes, also it thinks there are multiple JSON root elements

Comment: @GIJoe - It would if you put `[]` around the whole thing.  It's axiomatic that the OP will omit the outermost brackets around a JSON expression.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, you are right. I didn't think of trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching with a capturing group on "anything between brackets" (e.g. `\[(.*?)\]`) and adding the group to a list:

```
public static List<String> getStringsInBrackets(String s) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (m.find()) { list.add(m.group(1)); }
  return list;
}
```

For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String s = "[Munich, Germany],[Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada]";
  List<String> ss = getStringsInBrackets(s);
  ss.get(0); // => "Munich, Germany"
  ss.get(1); // => "Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada"
}
```

If performance becomes a concern you can pre-compile the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a Regex?  http://ideone.com/lZK0wo

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("[Munich, Germany],[Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada]");

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Line 1:  Munich, Germany
Line 2:  Jingle Pot Rd, Nanaimo, BC, Canada
```